# [WinForms]Multiple ComboBox dataBinding problem

Tags: c#, winforms

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    var item = new Item() { Index = i + 1, SelectedCode = 100 };

    string selectName = "keySelect" + (i + 1);
    Control found = groupBox1.Controls.Find(selectName, true).FirstOrDefault();
    if (found != null && found is ComboBox keySelect)
    {
        keySelect.DataSource = KeyBoardConst.AVAILABLE_KEYS;
        keySelect.DisplayMember = "text";
        keySelect.ValueMember = "value";
        keySelect.SelectedIndex = 0;

        keySelect.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", item, "SelectedCode");
    }
}
```

When any `ComboBox` selectChanged, all `ComboBox` change it's selected?

I'm sure bind different `ComboBox` with different Item. I'm sure the `ComboBox`'s hashcode is not same in every cycle. Please!

Comment: You need to give more info. What is the value of `KeyBoardConst.AVAILABLE_KEYS`?

Comment: Not related to the solution but do not check for `null` in the `if` clause. It is redundant. Just use `if (found is ComboBox keySelect)`. If the value of `found` is `null` then `found is ComboBox` will already give `false`.

Comment: @Mustafa Özçetin
Thank you for your help! I've got the reason.

Comment: @muk if you feel that your question and answer will be helpful to others with the same problem, it's OK to [Self-Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and this will also save time for people who might otherwise think that you still need a solution. If you feel the question _doesn't_ play to wide audience, it's also OK to withdraw (i.e. Delete) a question if it has no answers at all.

Comment: @IV. Thanks for the advice. I got it!

Answer (score 0):

I got the reason! If multiple ComboBox use the same DataSource, this problem will arise.
The solution is every combobox should use a different instance of the DataSourceObject.
e.g. use clone() or other way to create a new instance of the DataSouceObject.

I'm a newbee to .NET. This dataBinding behavior is really diffrent from VueJs